# Electrodynamics,Laplace equation

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

Well the classical image charge problem in electrodynamics,clearly shows a slick way of dealing with some symmetric cases.But that seems somewhat a way of doing back calculations.So could anyone link me with a actual solution of the Poisson equation in the case?